# Testing Visibility of Fields in a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, validation

I have a flow that has several fields in it, spread across multiple steps in a flow.
I have validation rules that need to be applied to the entire form when the user submits.
But those rules only apply to fields that show up conditionally.

Is their a way to test using Apex or anything actually if a field is visible and that its validated programmatically, instead of manually once the flow is live?

Comment: are you talking about validation rules that are applied at the schema level (i.e. SObject validation rules) or custom logic in your screen flow that validates the input prior to a DML element?

Comment: I actually have both cases ...

Answer (score 1):

Apex can't test the inner workings of a screen flow and conditional visibility.

If you want to verify Validation Rules are correct for all possible use cases, you would do something like the following (assuming inserts, adjust as needed for updates)

```
// Given inputs from various possible use cases
MyObject__c[] myObjs = new List<MyObj__c> {
   new MyObj__c(Fld1__c = 'x'),               // [0] use case 0 - valid
   new MyObj__c(Fld1__c = 'x', Fld2__c = 'y'),// [1] use case 1 - invalid
   ...
};
//  when inserted from Flow element
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(myObjs,false);
System.assertEquals(true,results[0].isSuccess(),'[0] is valid use case');
System.assertEquals(false,results[1].isSuccess(),'[1] is invalid use case'); 
...
// for the invalid use cases, you can also assert the error message
```

If you want to verify with automation that the screen flow transitions are correct, you'll need to use a [UX testing tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/01/ui-test-automation-on-salesforce.html) like Selenium or Provar.

Comment: I suspected as much.  What about if I used the metadata api to get information on the screenflow?  That is looking doubtful as I don't see any information on the visibility of elements in the payload that comes back from said api in the examples they gave anyway.

Comment: the metadata api defines the Flow's configuration, not its runtime state - basically, we're all waiting on a real test harness for screen flows from SFDC